# Service scheduled to start from Alarm Manager does not start

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-alarms, foreground-service

In my app I set an Alarm that when fired will start a foreground service.
I do it like this:

```
public class Stage2Alarm extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (!MyPrefs.isActivity1Visible()) {
        MyPrefs.setStageOneCompleted(true, context);
        StageNotification.sendNotification(context);
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}

public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Stage2Alarm.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, MyPrefs.getWakeUp(), alarmIntent);
}
```

}

The problem is it does not start the service at all, only the notification is being sent, what could be the problem?

EDIT: I also get NullPointerException in the LogCat when the service is supposed to start

EDIT 2: Here is the important part of the service

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    db = new DataHelper(this);
    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v("Service", intent.toString());
    initialize();
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Comment: where you are calling setAlarm this?

Comment: in an activity
private void setStageTwoAlarm() {
  Stage2Alarm alarm = new Stage2Alarm();
  alarm.setAlarm(this);
 }

Comment: just try this once,change(Intent intent = new Intent(context, Stage2Alarm.class)) to this (Intent intent = new Intent(context, Stage2Alarm.class)) and tell me what heppens.

Comment: umm, your examples are similar

Comment: sorry Intent intent = new Intent(context) change to this. also put your logcat, probelm seems to be in service class and with trigger of alarm.

Comment: intent can not have just one argument, I get an error

Comment: Post your service class

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
am = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                    + Constants.ALARM_MANAGER_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

In place of Intent use PendingIntent